# Rails Tutorial Chapter 10 (friendly forwarding) test error, Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <200: OK>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, railstutorial.org

Well, im new to coding with Rails and Michael Hartl tutorial is awesome, and till now i've benn able to find my coding errors... right now im in chapter 10 "Friendly Forwarding" and whilst performing the test for succesfull edit i stumbled on an error i cant see through.

**test_successful_edit_with_friendly_forwarding#UserEditTest (1.07s)
        Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <200: OK>
        test/integration/user_edit_test.rb:32:in `block in '**

my user_edit_test is:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserEditTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "unsuccessful edit" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    assert_template 'users/edit'
    patch user_path(@user), params: { user: { name:  "",
                                              email: "foo@invalid",
                                              password:              "foo",
                                              password_confirmation: "bar" } }

    assert_template 'users/edit'
  end

test "successful edit with friendly forwarding" do
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    log_in_as(@user)
    assert_redirected_to edit_user_url(@user)
    name  = "Foo Bar"
    email = "foo@bar.com"
    patch user_path(@user), params: { user: { name:  name,
                                              email: email,
                                              password:              "",
                                              password_confirmation: "" } }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to @user <---  this is line 32 from the test
    @user.reload
    assert_equal name,  @user.name
    assert_equal email, @user.email
  end
end
```

My users controller is:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  def show
    @user  = User.find(params[:id])
      end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params) # Not the final implementation!
    if @user.save
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
      end

  def update
       if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
          flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
          redirect_to @user
      # Handle a successful update.
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                 :password_confirmation)
    end 

#Before Filters

#Confirms a logged-in user
   def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        store_location
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end

    # Confirms the correct user.
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
end
```

My sessions.Helper is:

```
  module SessionsHelper

    #logs in the given user
    def log_in(user)
        session[:user_id] = user.id
    end

# Remembers a user in a persistent session.
  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end

    def current_user
           if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
 end 

#returns true if the current user is the given user
def current_user?(user)
  user == current_user
end

 # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
    def logged_in?
        !current_user.nil?
    end

def forget(user)
  user.forget
  cookies.delete(:user_id)
  cookies.delete(:remember_token)
end

 # Logs out current user
    def log_out
        forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
        @current_user = nil
    end

# Redirects to stored location (or to the default).
  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:forwarding_url] || default)
    session.delete(:forwarding_url)
  end

  # Stores the URL trying to be accessed.
  def store_location
    session[:forwarding_url] = request.original_url if request.get?
  end
end
```

And my Sessions Controller is:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in @user
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(@user) : forget(@user)
      redirect_back_or @user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

From what i've seen in other questions i understand the problem but can't seem to find a way to fix it, i feel is right there in my face but dont see it.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, your friendly forwarding is working correctly and is tested in the first 3 lines of your test case. The `assert_redirected_to @user` test corresponds to your UsersController#update, more specifically the `redirect_to @user` statement in the if branch. What happens if you log into the site and update a user's profile?  Check the logs at that point too.

Comment: Yes, yesterday i was doing a run at it and understanding further the code of the test and saw that the FF was performing ok... then i did a run on the App to see if the error displayed on the test came back... and no, it went perfect, i was able to submit the edit of the user, then review the changes... and the redirect was what i was expecting... sooo!!! still trying to figure it out

Comment: Did you ever sort this out?  Same sort of issue over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65964903/minitest-controller-updates-expected-response-to-be-a-3xx-redirect-but-was